# How to handle grids in bootstrap, grids inside grids

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have three columns(col-md-4) in my footer and first column has two divided columns(col-md-6) again. I want those two columns inside the first column to be together in mobile view. How should I partition.?

What I tried was something like,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">

</div>
```

But I am getting the two columns one below another in mobile, I want them to be in same grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `col-md-6` to `col-6` as this is Bootstrap's 4 smallest screen case. `col-md-6` will keep two columns next to each other on md (>=768px) sized screens and larger, but stack them below that breakpoint. And you will need to [wrap that inner set of divs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting) in a div with the class row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
</div>
```